# Calling PHP Serverside script using shell

Tags: php, shell

When I run client.sh script no output is coming. And when I use "system" command in php the client.sh script is running in infinite loop.

Server.sh:
code:

```
#!/bin/bash

while : 
do
        printf "Do you want to continue:[Y/N]\n"
        read ans
        case $ans in
                "Y")continue;;
                "N")echo "Thank you"
                    exit 0;;
                "*")echo "Wrong choice"
                   continue;;
        esac
done
```

Output:

```
srikanth@localhost:~/www/phpshell$ ./scm.sh
Do you want to continue:[Y/N]
Y
Do you want to continue:[Y/N]
N
Thank you
```

Calls.php:
Code:

```
<?php
$cmd="/home/srikanth/phptest/server.sh";
pcntl_exec($cmd);
?>
```

Output:

```
srikanth@localhost:~/phptest$ php calls.php 
Do you want to continue:[Y/N]
Y
Do you want to continue:[Y/N]
N
Thank you
```

Client.sh 
code:

```
#!/bin/bash
curl http://cxps103/svnadmin/calls.php
```

Output:

```
srikanth@localhost:~/phptest$ ./client.sh
```

Any suggestion would be of much help. Thank you.

**Update:**

As per Ibu's suggestion am simplifying my question, I had got the problem, there is a while loop in my `server.sh` script which causing a problem,

Comment: Wow this a lot to read, how about you write only the part that is having a problem

Comment: @lbu, I am having a problem only with client.sh script which is not showing any output on the terminal. Request to let me know how can I call the calls.php script. Thanks in advance

Comment: If you don't have a webserver running then the "curl" is pretty meaningless.

Comment: Err, what do you expect? That the bash script will run, display the menu and ask for your choice in a webbrowser? If that's the case, guess again, because it will never work as-is.

Comment: @wimvds, I want the script to be run in terminal. I dont require the display in webbrowser. I had modified my question as per Ibu's suggestion.

Comment: @James Anderson, I have a webserver running.

Comment: Why are you trying to run this through a web request (using curl)? As I said : this will never work, and it doesn't make any sense. If you want to run an interactive bash script on a remote server use SSH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the CGI script (`server.sh`) runs, its standard input is not connected to anything. Therefore the `read` command always sets `ans` to an empty value, which doesn't match any of the alternatives in the `case` statement, and the script loops forever.

As [wimvds](https://stackoverflow.com/users/109822/wimvds) and others have remarked, your approach is fundamentally wrong. A CGI script generates an HTML page to display in a browser. It acts based on a client request. Once the script has its arguments, it doesn't get input from anywhere (unless it opens files on the server). Interaction for a web application consists of the user entering data in a form and pressing a submit button. Unix interactions such as entering input on stdin and seeing output on stdout don't work over HTTP.

Aside: the `"*")` case would only match a line consisting of a single `*` character. You probably meant `*)`, meaning to match anything.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me. I will use the SSH method to generate interactive bash script. Thanks once again.